# Not able to set value of input field

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to check if an object has a value and does not throw an error. If so, pass it as the value of an input field.

```js
export class DialogServiceTabletAddRowComponent implements OnInit {
  service?: string;

  constructor(private _dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogServiceTabletAddRowComponent>, private _fb: FormBuilder, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ServiceDataToDialog) {
    try {
      this.service = this.data[this.data.id].allServices[this.data.id][this.data.id].service;
    }
    catch (e) {
      this.service = '';
    }
    console.log(this.service);
    })

  }

  mainForm = this._fb.group({
    service: [this.service, Validators.required]
  })


}
```

`console.log(this.service);` gives me the correct value but the value of my input field is still empty. How comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `this.mainForm = this._fb.group...` code in the constructor after the try/catch. Also add `public mainForm: FormGroup` as a class property

The issue here is how TypeScript handles initializing class properties. Under the hood it initializes them immediately inside the constructor